# Sending username and password to the server and getting response in Android

Tags: android

How can I send my username and password to the server and get response from the server using httpclient in Android? I researched many websites but I couldn't find anything I want.

Comment: Your question isn't unclear.
What username and password? What server? What response are you expecting?

Comment: You have to make **web service** on the server-side. Then there are at least 2 ways to send the data to the server and get the response from your code. Search for `HttpPost` & `HttpUrlConnection`. The first is easier to use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make a class Adapter and put this code...Here i assume you are using json webService.

```
public String login(String uname, String password)
{
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    try 
    {   
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("Your Url");

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emailid", uname));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        is = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // convert response to string
    try 
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }

        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();

        Log.v("log","Result: " + result);
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.v("log", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

and make a call like this...

```
Adapter adb = new Adapter();
response = adb.login(edtLoginemail.getText().toString(), edtLoginPassword.getText().toString());
```

Comment: @mehul-ranpara how can i send `emailid` and `password` using array.eg.. `user_auth`

Comment: @Sameera you can pass array to this class and from that you can take value for ex :L arr.get(0)-- user_auth or arr.get(1)-- user_password etc.

Comment: @mehul-ranpara can you please help me in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053916/how-to-send-json-data-from-android-to-php-url/27054118?noredirect=1#comment42626602_27054118

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might help you.

```
userId = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" 
            + "<login><User>" + userId + "</User>"
            + "<Password>" + password + "</Password></login>";
            serverCall(xml);


serverCall(xml);


private void serverCall(final String xml )
{

 ConnectivityManager conMan = ( ConnectivityManager ) getSystemService( Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
 if( conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected() )
  {

     result = new Connection().getResponse("http://localhost/login.php" , xml);
     if(result.equals("yes") {
       //registration done
     } else {
       //failed
     }
   }
}
```

Connection.java

```
public String getResponse(String connUrl, String xml) {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = null;
    try {
        MultipartEntity mp = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        HttpPost method = new HttpPost(connUrl);
        method.setEntity(mp);
        mp.addPart("xml_request", new StringBody(xml));

        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(method);

        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
            ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(outstream);
            return outstream.toString();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.v("APP", "Exception while create connection for getResponse from server with: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a web service on the **server-side**.

Then there are at least 2 ways to send the data to the server and get the response from your code. Search for `HttpPost` & `HttpUrlConnection`. The first is easier to use to send data with the method **POST**, but is also a LOT more slow.